# Get rid of a AlertView that pops up when a webpage is loaded.

Tags: iphone

When I load a URL in UIWebView, an Alert pops up that prompts the user to download their app from the app store(presumably, the creators of the website were able to instantiate a UIAlertView using javascript or HTML5. I have no idea how though). I don't want the alerts to show up. Anyone know how to disable such a feature in the UIWebView?

Comment: Write some piece of your code. Show us the code of webViewDidFinishLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the window.alert function with a blank function:

```
window.alert = function () {};
```

You can apply this on to a UIWebView using `stringByEvaluatingJavascript:`.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as correct, so the question is marked correctly and future readers can see the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is alert(); JavaScript command. You can turn it off only by turning JavaScript off for the whole Safari on your iPhone in Settings -> Safari -> JavaScript.